# Powerbuilder 6.5 not able to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 after disabling TLS1.0

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder, tls1.0, tls1.1

We are using PB 6.5 version, which uses ntwdblib.dll for DB connection, We are suing SQL Server 2008 R2. recently TLS1.0 on the SQL Server is disabled. As a result, we are not able to access the database from PB. Every time when the application tries to open the connection, it throws an error

> Server not found for (DB server)

However the same database can be accessed from the same system using SSMS or .NET applications.

How can we overcome with this issue?

Comment: Your organization (or client) has waited FAR too long to upgrade tools. Version 7 is more than 20 years old - and neither that nor your version of sql server are supported any longer. It looks like you will need to re-enable TLS and live with the security implications.

Comment: I forgot to mention, issue occurring while connection from DEV machine to DEV DB. We don't have any issue with QA or Prod. even with disable of TLS 1.0 everything working on QA and Prod.

Comment: You have a networking issue and there are many discussions about enabling or disabling versions of TLS. It can be done on the client machine or the server machine. This is a discussion you should have with your network team to figure out where it is disabled.

Comment: You DEV machine likely doesn't have the MSOLEDBSQL provider libraries installed.  But @SMor is correct - you are WAY behind.  SO will only take you so far - better to update to newer, supported technologies